# Control upload and download speeds in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I was wondering if it is possible to control the upload or download speed of a specific task in Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10?

I have an uploading task in particular that significantly reduces my download speed.

Comment: Nice question :) I want that too. Although for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Well, up until Firefox 3.5, I was using an extension called Firefox Throttle but it's not compatible with later versions of the browser.

The most effective way to do throttling is by using a router that has this feature or, if you already have a compatible router, you might want to consider overwriting the factory firmware with DD-WRT, OpenWRT or Tomato (all have application-oriented QoS).

Another option would be to use wondershaper and trickle. They're Linux applications; you can probably 'apt-get install' them.

I just couldn't find a Firefox extension that can throttle bandwidth that's compatible with latest Firefox versions (3.6 and up).